# Enable arrow key navigation in input prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-prompt, read-eval-print-loop

Simple input loop

```
while True:
    query = input('> ')
    results = get_results(query)
    print(results)
```

Doesn't allow me to use arrow keys to

1. Move cursor backwards through entered text to change something
2. Press up arrow to get entries entered in the past
3. Press down arrow to move in the opposite direction to (2)

Instead it just prints all the escape codes:

```
> my query^[[C^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[A^[[A^[[A
```

How can I make it behave like a REPL or shell prompt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cmd` module to create a cmd interpreter class like below.

```
import cmd

class CmdParse(cmd.Cmd):
    prompt = '> '
    commands = []
    def do_list(self, line):
        print(self.commands)
    def default(self, line):
        print(line[::])
        # Write your code here by handling the input entered
        self.commands.append(line)
    def do_exit(self, line):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CmdParse().cmdloop()
```

Attaching the output of this program on trying few commands below:

```
mithilesh@mithilesh-desktop:~/playground/on_the_fly$ python cmds.py 
> 123
123
> 456
456
> list
['123', '456']
> exit
mithilesh@mithilesh-desktop:~/playground/on_the_fly$
```

For more info, refer the [docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/CmdModule)

Comment: Thanks Mithilesh. That's quite helpful. I was looking for similar functionality in the Nodejs world. Do you know of any npm package that does this? Or I've to look into this `cmd` module source code.

Comment: I am not aware of `Nodejs`. Google search gave me this package. Please validate it. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd
Thanks!

Comment: No. That provides different functionalities. It merely executes any command, equivalent to Python's `os.system()` and `subprocess.run()`. I found an equivalent support in the Nodejs itself: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html.. and no `npm` package is required.

Answer (score 0):

`cmd` library of python does nothing fancy. It also calls `input` internally. What enables arrow keys and other slightly more advanced features such as autocomplete is `readline` import.

So all you need to do is:

```py
import readline
a = input('>')
```